# TypeError: string indices must be integers - Python JSON

Tags: python, json, parsing

Getting `TypeError: string indices must be integers` on the `my_object` instantiation here below (3rd line of method)

```
def get_note_retrieval_body(event):
    sns_body = event["Records"][0]["Sns"]
    message = json.loads(sns_body["Message"])
    my_object = message["data"]["getNotes"]
    return my_object
```

I get the following (account numbers etc are marked with XXX) when i use str(event) and then json format it, so this will tell you what the event looks like

```
{
    'Records': [{
        'EventSource': 'aws:sns',
        'EventVersion': '1.0',
        'EventSubscriptionArn': 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:XXXXXX:topic-name-sandbox:7XXXX',
        'Sns': {
            'Type': 'Notification',
            'MessageId': 'd1074c88-ae21-52b6-8a75-1b07d766cfdd',
            'TopicArn': 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:XXXXXXX:topic-name',
            'Subject': None,
            'Message': '"{\\"data\\": {\\"getNotes\\": {\\"claimNumber\\": \\"AAAB09000010\\", \\"dateEntered\\": \\"2010-04-22T08:03:53\\",\\"categoryCode\\": \\"fdf49\\",\\"subCategoryCode\\": \\"ATT\\", \\"fileNoteTextDetails\\": [{\\"fileNoteText\\": {\\"fileNoteID\\": \\"112B40FE42934055\\", \\"noteText\\": \\"Send Acknowledgement Letter to Claimant\\", \\"authorID\\": \\"0\\"}, \\"fileNoteAttachments\\": [{\\"attachment\\": {\\"fileName\\": \\"F70F880879D35FC4.doc\\", \\"fileExtension\\": \\".URL\\", \\"dateCreated\\": \\"2010-04-22T08:59:57\\", \\"createdBy\\": \\"CLONER\\", \\"dateUpdated\\": \\"2020-07-30T08:36:19.1903051\\", \\"updatedBy\\": \\"EVERYONE\\"}}]}], \\"fileNoteExtendedEntityData\\": {\\"dateOnDocument\\": \\"2010-04-22T08:59:57\\", \\"serviceDateFrom\\": \\"2010-04-22T08:59:57\\", \\"serviceDateThrough\\": \\"2010-04-22T08:59:57\\", \\"author\\": \\"n0000000\\"}}}}"',
            'Timestamp': '2020-07-20T10:50:47.850Z',
            'SignatureVersion': '1',
            'Signature': 'XXXXXX',
            'SigningCertUrl': 'https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/XXXcert.pem',
            'UnsubscribeUrl': 'https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:XXXXXX:topic-name-sandbox:7XX'.
            'MessageAttributes': {}
        }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you run `json.loads` on `sns_body["Message"]`, you still get back a string. You can run `json.loads` twice, and that should solve the issue.

`sns_body["Message"]` is quoted twice (i.e., it is wrapped in single quotes and double quotes). So when you try to decode it once, you still get back a string, but this time it is only quoted once. Then a second `json.loads` will decode the string into a dictionary.

```
def get_note_retrieval_body(event):
    sns_body = event["Records"][0]["Sns"]
    message = json.loads(json.loads(sns_body["Message"]))
    my_object = message["data"]["getNotes"]
    return my_object
```

Comment: I don't want to change the code, this is something I am picking up after someone else and I want to write a test, so would be more interested in changing the JSON payload.

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question. In that case, change the string to whatever `json.loads` outputs.

Comment: I know yea only thinking of it now, I'll be at laptop tomorrow if this works I'll accept the answer